# install Ubuntu server from internal HDD

Tags: dual-boot, server, partitioning, hard-drive

I am using an old laptop from a business. The DVD drive wont open and no matter what I do in win7, I cannot get USB ports to work. Ethernet and wifi are fine.

I want to set this laptop up as an Ubuntu server for testing purposes since its a 64bit 1.9GHz processor with 4GB ram.

Can i install Ubuntu server or even Ubuntu desktop directly from a partitioned hdd within the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu from a live cd/dvd/usb to an empty hard drive or even one that contains another OS. But this apparently isn't an option in your computer. So you need to find an external cd or dvd reader. There are other more unusual options:
If you have a hard drive with a fully installed and working copy of Ubuntu on it you can insert that hard drive in your computer and it should work.
You can also clone the contents of a hard drive to another hard drive and then both hard drives will contain a working copy of Ubuntu. I would not recommend this last option because it has no benefit over installing Ubuntu from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

`Windows 7` include a built-in functionality in `Disk Management` to shrink and expand partitions.

To get to this utility, open up `Control Panel`, and type in `partition` into the search box.. you’ll immediately see the link `Administrative Tools`

In the Disk Management screen, just `right-click` on the partition that you want to shrink, and select `Shrink Volume` from the menu.

In the Shrink dialog, you will want to enter the amount you want to shrink by, not the new size.

If you want to shrink your `60gb` partition by roughly `20gb` so that it will now be roughly 40gb, enter `20000` into the box.

Download ubuntu server image.iso:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.2/ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso

Move your `ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso` to the root file of your hard drive (for instance C:)

Download `EasyBCD` from here:

https://neosmart.net/forums/threads/easybcd-2-3-beta-builds.642/

Make sure you get the latest build, (you will need to register on the forum first)

Install `Easy BCD` and then run it.

Click `External Devices`, then `ISOboot`

Browse to the path of the `ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso` you wish to add.

Give it a name, `ubuntu server` then click `Create Entry`.

Next time you boot you will have the option of booting to `ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso`.

Install Ubuntu alongside Windows as this guide, with manual partitioning.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot